# retrieving the response of a POST in NodeJS

Tags: json, node.js

I am receiving below response from a service

```
[ { recipient_id: 'default',
    text: 'Hello, how can I help?' } ]
```

I need to retrieve the `text` portion of the response. I can do that with python like below

```
json_response = response.json()
reply = json_response[0]['text']
```

But I need to retrieve the `text` portion in NodeJS now for a different project. So I have tried below code but it outputs `undefined`

```
var obj = JSON.parse(response)
console.log(obj[0]['text'])
```

Can anyone please suggest?

**EDIT:**

The POST request is made like

```
request.post(
                  'http://path-to-service',
                  { json: { 'query': msg} },
                  function (error, response, body) {
                      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                          console.log(body)
                          var obj = JSON.parse(body)
                          console.log(obj[0]['text'])

                      }
```

The problem is the service returns response as an array of python dictionary. So `response[0]` is essentially a python dictionary

```
{ recipient_id: 'default',
  text: 'Hello, how can I help?' }
```

So the question is, how do I retrieve the value of the key `text` from this dictionary.

Comment: can you show us briefly how you are receiving it? Perhaps it is parsed automatically and is already an object.

Comment: @dgig added mode details

Comment: when you `console.log(body)`, does it show as a string or as an object? It seems to me you can do `console.log(body[0].text)` immediately after checking for an error.

Comment: Could you describe the output? What does the `console.log(obj[0]['text'])` print?  Is there an error message instead?  Please click "Edit" and add that to your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your response is already coming as `JSON` object so don't need to parse again.

```js
var obj =  [ { recipient_id: 'default',
    text: 'Hello, how can I help?' } ];
    
 console.log(obj[0].text);
```

Answer (score 0):

try code

```
var body = {'query': 'msg', 'name': 'my name is nodejs'}
var obj = JSON.parse(body);
console.log(obj.query);
console.log(obj.name);
```

printf

```
msg
my name is nodejs
```